# how to make dislike button display immediately after liking it and vice versa? In Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have successfully created a like button which works, and if i like a post the counter is incremented and it doesn't show the unlike button immediately, I have to refresh the page for it display and even after refreshing it says like, instead of unlike but if I click on it it reduces the count i.e unlikes it.

So how to make dislike button display immediately after liking it and vice versa? Thank you.

Here's the code:

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
def like_post(request):
    liked = False
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']
        post = Post.objects.get(id=int(post_id))
        if request.session.get('has_liked_'+post_id, liked):
            print("unlike")
            if post.likes > 0:
                likes = post.likes - 1
                try:
                    del request.session['has_liked_'+post_id]
                except KeyError:
                    print("keyerror")
        else:
            print("like")
            request.session['has_liked_'+post_id] = True
            likes = post.likes + 1
    post.likes = likes
    post.save()
    return HttpResponse(likes, liked)

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post_id = post.pk
    liked = False
    if request.session.get('has_liked_' + str(post_id), liked):
        liked = True
        print("liked {}_{}".format(liked, post_id))
    context = {'post': post, 'liked': liked}
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'like_post/$', views.like_post, name='like_post'),
```

ajax-blog.js

```
$('#likes').click(function(){
    var postid;
    postid= $(this).attr("data-post_id");
    $.get('/blog/like_post/', {post_id: postid}, function(data){
               $('#like_count').html(data);
               $('#likes').hide();
    });
});
```

**post_detail.html**

```
<p>
    <strong id="like_count">{{ post.likes }}</strong> people like this category

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <button id="likes" data-post_id="{{post.id}}"  class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
    {% if liked %}
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
        Unlike
        </button>
    {% else %}
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
        Like
        </button>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#likes').click(function(){
    $('.like_span').toggleClass('glyphicon-thumbs-down glyphicon-thumbs-up');
    var postid;
    postid= $(this).attr("data-post_id");
    $.get('/blog/like_post/', {post_id: postid, liked:$('.like_span').hasClass('glyphicon-thumbs-up')}, function(data){
               $('#like_count').html(data);
               $('#likes').hide();
    });
});
```

Then add class `like_span`

```
<span class="like_span glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
<span class="like_span glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
```

Then in views you will get `request.GET['liked']` as true or false.Treat that value for increase and decrease

Answer (score 0):

One of the good ways to handle is not to refresh the page when user click on like or dislike.

Instead, use [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) with [rest api(DRF)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) to **increase** and **decrease** the like count.

Use jquery to switch the icons instead of django template tag condition `{% if liked %}`

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know much in JS can you please help me with that for increasing and decreasing the count i have a js but how i have no idea about how to switch icons